# Android: How to give a LinearLayout a maximum width?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I am designing a layout for my Android app.

I want a `LinearLayout` within a ScrollView to stretch. I achieved this with layout_width:match_parent. However, I don't want to stretch it beyond 500dp.

The layout should look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D25B7.jpg

So far I've tried android:maxWidth and                 app:layout_constraintWidth_max (with `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_width="match_parent")`.

How does on achieve this layout without extra files for certain screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the width of the linearLayout programmatically in onCreate() for each screen mode:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll);

        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        else {
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```